Web.Config rewrite rule for Angular application to handle invalid files/directories
I have a web.config rewrite rule setup for angular application as below
 <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(?!^bff).*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>

Problem: The issue is that Angular allows requests for non-existent files to return a 200 OK status, causing the application to hang at the current route since the request cannot be served.
for ex: http://domain/svg/fileexist.svg - file exists and return with status 200
http://domain/svg/filenotexisit.svg - file does not exist but passed with status 200 and app hangs
Expected Result: The Angular application should continue to allow requests for files and directories, but should return a 404 status if an invalid file or directory is requested.
for ex: http://domain/svg/fileexist.svg - file exists and return with status 200
http://domain/svg/filenotexisit.svg - file does not exist and should return status 404
Observation: This behavior works correctly in a basic Angular 17 app running locally. However, when the Angular app is hosted on IIS with the specified web.config rewrite rule, IIS does not handle invalid file requests properly.
Request for Assistance: Any suggestions on how to address this scenario would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks everyone for your contribution.
I have solved this problem by adding another rule just above the existing rule
<match url="\.\w{2,4}($)" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="404" />
</rule>



http://domain/svg/filenotexisit.svg - file does not exist but passed with status 200 and app hangs

I'm not sure about your actual test URL, but I guess that URL also matches the expression in the rule, so it execute the rewrite action, which changes the response.
The URL you configured is /, which may point to some default pages (existing, such as index.html, default.html), so it returns 200. Please check it.
If I misunderstood something, please provide more details, such as a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

we hosted this angular app on azure app service on windows env. So this has a web.config where we have all the policies, rules..etc.. setup. Add the above rule and try accessing any resource that doesn't exist, you will notice 200OK.

You need to check what I mentioned, whether a non-existent file path can also trigger the rewrite rule.
